Losing bloc state after using Navigator.of().pop
I have a bottomAppBar with 3 page link and a button in middle for a pop dialog.
When closing a showModalBottomSheet dialog after an successfull/failed event it removes the dialog but then defaults to a blank page. This only happens in the 2 pages I have a BlocConsumer in.
I'm using Navigator.of(context).pop(); to close the navigator.
If I add an explicit bloc to it then it works but it needs to be for the right page.
context.read<HabitsBloc>().add(HabitsFetchAllHabits())
I'm guessing is that it's not refetching the initState() again of the previous page when closing the dialog, but don't think I need to do that.
User Flow Explanation:
HomePage - Has a button that Triggers a showModalBottomSheet
HomePage - Has a bottom appbar with 3 pages, 2 of them are stateful with blocconsumers.
Dialog failure will trigger this to showsnackbar and remove the dialog with the pop();
 if (state is HabitEntrySaveFailure) {
        showOverlaySnackBar(context, state.error);
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        
  }

If the page/widget that was behind on the stack is in a BlocConsumer nothing inside the builder will be displayed, it's like the state is missing or something
   body: BlocConsumer<HabitsBloc, HabitsState>(
    listener: (context, state) {
      if (state is HabitsGetFailure) {
        showSnackBar(context, state.error);
      }
    },
    builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is HabitsLoading) {
        return const Loader();
      }
      if (state is HabitsGetSuccess) {

So the context of HabitsGetSuccess seems to have been removed and a blank page is displayed as that's what I have as a fallback.
But if I add this to the above listener then it works fine, but i'd rather not do that as there are are another two pages with different Bloc events which the user could have triggered the dialog from on the appbar index.
        if (state is HabitEntrySaveFailure) {
        print('HabitEntry Failure here');
        showOverlaySnackBar(context, state.error);
      
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        context.read<HabitsBloc>().add(HabitsFetchAllHabits());
        
      }

source code link:https://pastebin.com/5b1JR8Vu

The problem isn't clear, can you add more details or your code?

ok i've updated it to give a more detailed example.

I think using multi bloc provider could solve your issue and the app will not loose the state of navigation bar you can read this article I think it would hep you
bloc_documentation

I'm already using a multi bloc provider for my app, the only thing is I'm not handling the routing with bloc, the bottom nav is just based on current index mapped to pages.

Please show me the full code to be able to help you (for the navigation and its bloc)

sure Ayman here it is https://pastebin.com/5b1JR8Vu

Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
showOverlaySnackBar(context, "success!!!");
Why you need push and remove ?
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, HomePage.route(), (route) => false);   I think by removing push and remove and only using pop before showing toast would solve your issue let me know what happens also check if you are doing double pop try to log the success and failure events
